# Force remove the user.config during uninstall?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, setup-project

how do i code the custom action during the uninstall? 
Would it require a batch file?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user.config data gets stored in the `%APPDATA%\ProjectName` folder.

If you want to remove the user.config data when you uninstall then you can just use the `System.IO.Directory.Delete("%APPDATA%\ProjectName");`

Note: You can get the installed path using the following `Context.Parameters["assemblypath"]` this is the path that the user selects to install the project.

Comment: the user.config get's created in this location: C:\Users\ [User] \AppData\Local\[Company]\[Project Name].vshos_Url_zw3i045fzlcuakzzn3dtaw3fqgh03sub\1.0.0.0; i dont think its the same location

Comment: @Martin Ongtangco, yeah thats correct. But if you want to remove all the user.config settings you can just delete this folder. C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local[Company][Project Name]

Comment: apparently, the "Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Company Name")" does not give me the user but "All Users"

Comment: Please take a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022430/specialfolder-applicationdata-returning-default-user , it looks like you need to run the Applicaion as the currently logged in User. Then it should work.

Comment: Also see this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407932/get-logged-in-user

Comment: even with the right path, i think the uninstall code is not allowed to remove that particular folder.

Comment: Is will be, when you run the installer in normally runs with elevated privilages, thats why it can create those folders. When you run the uninstaller just use a try catch, and if there is an error then use the MessageBox.Show("error occured. " + e.ToString()); to show that an error occured and we can then see from the error whats actually happening.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, based on the answer above.  For my app I only allow per user installs, not "all users" so I don't have to worry about uninstalling for multiple users, or for users other than the current user running uninstall.  If you allow "all user" installs, you'll have some issues to work out.

```
    public override void Uninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
    {
        String p = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CompanyName");
        string[] ss = Directory.GetDirectories(p, "ProjectName.*");
        foreach (string s in ss)
        {
            if(MessageBox.Show("Delete " + s + "?","Delete Settings?",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                Directory.Delete(s, true);
        }
        base.Uninstall(savedState);
    }
```

I'm not actually going to leave the prompt in there, that is just for testing to make sure I'm not deleting the wrong folders on my PC.. until this code has been fully tested.  CompanyName and ProjectName need to be changed to match your project.

I might add a page to uninstall UI or just a prompt to ask if they want to delete all settings (so they can choose not to if they are going to reinstall).

Answer (score 2):

```
var filePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%userprofile%\APPDATA/ProjectName");
System.IO.Directory.Delete(filePath );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom action to trigger an executable while install or uninstall or both. 
for eg: create an .exe which will delete the user.config folder. Add this exe in binary table. Add an entry in CustomAction table with Source being the foreign key to name in Binary table and TArget being the actual exe file name and type = 2. Now add this action in InstallExecuteSequence with whatever sequence order you wish to trigger the .exe in installation process.

Answer (score 0):

1) [Create a custom action (article includes pictures)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335516/Custom-Action-in-Visual-Studio-setup-projects)

2) Handle the `Uninstall` event of the custom action

```
  [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)]
    public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            path = Path.Combine(path, "{Your application folder name}");
            Directory.Delete(path, true);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
        }
        base.Uninstall(savedState);
    }
```